# Unable to use inject without observer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, tsx

I'm currently using typed React (TSX) and mobx for state management.

I am able to build a component which uses both observer and inject decorators. But I am not able to build a component which uses inject without observer.

This passes the typescript compiler

```
export const DealershipBreadCrumb = inject("appStore")(observer((props: Props) => {
    const {appStore} = props;
    const dealership = appStore.getSelectedDealership();
    return (
          <div className="filter__container filter__group">
            <a className="filter__link" href={`cars?q=${appStore.searchResults.searchQuery}`}>
              <span className="filter__text">{dealership.name}</span>
            </a>
          </div>
      )
    }))
```

However this fails

```
export const DealershipBreadCrumb = inject("appStore")((props: Props) => {
```

With the following error message

```
[ts] Argument of type '(props: Props) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<{}>'.
   Type '(props: Props) => Element' provides no match for the signature 'new (props?: {}, context?: any): Component<{}, ComponentState>'
```

Please assist me in making heads and tails of this error message. My bet is that the typings are out of date or something. Or otherwise the use of inject without observer is actually an invalid combination.

Comment: Which `.d.ts` file are you using for `mobx-react`? Do you have a link for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your error is coming from this:`((props: Props)...`
when using inject that way I believe it is expecting a function, try use it like this:
`export const DealershipBreadCrumb = inject('SystemDataStore')((props => {`

btw don't forget that if you want to use inject without observer it will inject the last values of that store but it wont be aware of any change of values.

Comment: That's not a problem, as I will only be writing to the store in the case of this component.